# pythonで行を削除したいです

Tags: python, python3

pythonについての質問です。
全ての要素の値が0である行を削除するにはどのようなコードを書けばよいでしょうか。
例えば、

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[0,0,0],[3,3,3]])
```

とあった場合に、aの一行目と4行目を削除したいです。

Answer (score 4):

```
a[a.any(axis=1), :]
```

でよいのではないでしょうか

Answer (score 0):

配列に0が含まれていないか、含まれていた場合も0だけではない　配列をフィルターするようにすると、以下のコードで可能です。

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([[0,0,0],[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[0,0,0],[3,3,3],[0,1,2,3]])
a=filter(lambda x: not 0 in x or len(set(x)) > 1, a)
```

出力結果

> [[1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2], [3, 3, 3], [0, 1, 2, 3]]

Comment: この手法を使うとCの配列であるnumpyオブジェクトからpythonのジェネレータオブジェクトに変換されているので、実行速度が低下するのと、numpyとして扱うためにはまたnp.arrayを呼び出す必要があるのであまりおススメできないです。

Comment: @naokifujita なるほど。そうなんですね。コメント、ありがとございます！